# Compute Lagrange polynomial factors

Tags: polynomials, factoring, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

Consider the Lagrange polynomial of degree $n$ with uniform spacing, which interpolates points $p_0, ..., p_n$ in the following form:

$a_0 + a_1 t + a_2 * t^2 + a_3 t^3 + ... + a_n t^n$

How is it possible to compute the list of successive $a_i$ values?

An example for $n=3$ (cubic) case with $t_0 = 1, t_2 = 2, t_2 = 3, t_3 = 4$:

$-\frac{1}{6} \left(p_0-3 p_1+3 p_2-p_3\right) t^3+\frac{1}{2} \left(3 p_0-8 p_1+7 p_2-2 p_3\right) t^2-\frac{1}{6} \left(26 p_0-57 p_1+42 p_2-11 p_3\right) t+4 p_0-6 p_1+4 p_2-p_3$

so

$a_0 = 4 p_0-6 p_1+4 p_2-p_3$

$a_1 = \frac{1}{6} \left(26 p_0-57 p_1+42 p_2-11 p_3\right)$

$a_2 = \frac{1}{2} \left(3 p_0-8 p_1+7 p_2-2 p_3\right)$

$a_3 = -\frac{1}{6} \left(p_0-3 p_1+3 p_2-p_3\right)$

and with $t_0 = 0, t_1 = 1, t_2 = 2, t_3 = 3$ (which is preferable):

$-\frac{1}{6} \left(p_0-3 p_1+3 p_2-p_3\right) t^3+\frac{1}{2} \left(2 p_0-5 p_1+4 p_2-p_3\right) t^2-\frac{1}{6} \left(11 p_0-18 p_1+9 p_2-2 p_3\right) t+p_0$

so

$t_0 = p_0$

$t_1 = -\frac{1}{6} \left(11 p_0-18 p_1+9 p_2-2 p_3\right)$

$t_2 = \frac{1}{2} \left(2 p_0-5 p_1+4 p_2-p_3\right)$

$t_3 = -\frac{1}{6} \left(p_0-3 p_1+3 p_2-p_3\right)$

Comment: For what $t_n$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Good catch. My example is computed with uniform parametrization, but if possible, then custom $t_i$ values should be supported.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy formula for the general case. For efficient computation, one normally uses the Neville scheme that works by incorporating the points one after another. This can be done symbolically (i.e. evaluating the expressions of the polynomial coefficients), but I guess that for large $n$ the formulas get terrible.

Comment: You can also express the problem as a system of linear equations, where the matrix is of the Vandermonde form. This makes the main determinant trivial to obtain, but I don't know about the other ones.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I know the Neville scheme, but with the presented formula $\Sigma(a_i t^i)$ it can be computed more efficiently numerically, sacrificing some amount of numerical stability.

Comment: What makes you say that it is more efficient ? The computation of the coefficients themselves has a cost.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Very simple: the number of operations. You can precompute $a_i$. Then at evaluating the polynomial perform only some multiplications and additions, or even better: fused-multiply-adds.

Comment: Ok if precomputation is allowed.

Comment: I updated my question with an example for $t_0 = 0, t_1 = 1, t_2 = 2, t_3 = 3$. That is preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To precompute the coefficients, you solve

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&t_0&t_0^2&\cdots&t_0^{n-1}\\
1&t_1&t_1^2&\cdots&t_1^{n-1}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
1&t_{n-1}&t_{n-1}^2&\cdots&t_{n-1}^{n-1}\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a_0\\a_1\\\vdots\\a_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}p_0\\p_1\\\vdots\\p_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}.$$

If you want to get the solution for arbitrary $p_k$, simply compute the matrix inverse. You can find a general formula here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Vandermonde%27s_Matrix.

---

For instance
$$\begin{bmatrix}1& 0& 0& 0\\1& 1&1&1\\1&2&4&8\\1&3&9& 27\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}1& 0& 0& 0\\-11/6& 3& -3/2& 1/3\\1& -5/2& 2& -1/2\\-1/6& 1/2& -1/2& 1/6\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: What you mean on arbitrary $p_k$? This way $p$ values are already arbitrary.

Comment: I mean not knowing them in advance, formulas in terms of unknown $p_k$, i.e. what you were asking for.